# How to align the left hand skill type?

Tags: environments

Within the following piece of code I wish to align the skill type with the top of the text written on the right hand side. Otherwise the text becomes difficult to separate. This is from a template CV from the following [site](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/awesome-cv).

Attached are the pieces of code I need to edit. I have tried adding vertical spaces and modifying the awesome-cv.cls part too. Each time getting an error.  Any help is much appreciated!! :)

[image]

```
% Define an environment for cvskill
\newenvironment{cvskills}{%
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r L{\textwidth * \real{0.9}}}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}
% Define a line of cv information(skill)
% Usage: \cvskill{<type>}{<skillset>}
\newcommand*{\cvskill}[2]{%
    \skilltypestyle{#1} & \skillsetstyle{#2} \\
}

% Define an environment for cvitems(for cventry)
\newenvironment{cvitems}{%
  \vspace{-4mm}
  \begin{justify}
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2ex, nosep, noitemsep]
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\bullet}
}{%
  \end{itemize}
  \end{justify}
  \vspace{-2mm}
}
```

Comment: Look up the minipage env and its optional argument for aligning text in two of those next to each other

Comment: And please post fully compilable minimal examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the environment `cvskill` uses the earlier created `L`-column for the second column, which uses `m{#1}` as a basis. Therefore, it is aligned at vertical center. change this to `p{#1}`, and it is aligned at vertical top. To not mess up anything else, I have created a `\newcolumntype{K}`:

```
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
```

Then we replace `L` with `K`in the `\cvskill`:

```
% Define an environment for cvskill
\newenvironment{cvskills}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r K{\textwidth * \real{0.9}}}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
```

[image: Image from my own CV]

(Image is taken from my own CV, with some added text, but illustrates the behavior.)